# How to make array of protocol at the same time conform to Equatable?

Tags: ios, swift

The following code compiled without issue

```
protocol Animal {
}

var animals = [Animal]()
```

---

However, we have a new requirement, where we need to compare array of `Animal`

```
protocol Animal {
}

func x(a0: [Animal], a1: [Animal]) -> Bool {
    return a0 == a1
}

var animals = [Animal]()
```

The above code will yield compilation error

> protocol 'Animal' as a type cannot conform to 'Equatable'

---

We tend to fix by

```
protocol Animal: Equatable {
}

func x(a0: [Animal], a1: [Animal]) -> Bool {
    return a0 == a1
}

var animals = [Animal]()
```

At array declaration line, we are getting error

> protocol 'Animal' can only be used as a generic constraint because it
> has Self or associated type requirements

May I know,

1. Why we can have an array of protocol, before the protocol is conforming to Equatable?
2. Why we are not allowed to have an array of protocol, once the protocol is conforming to Equatable?
3. What are some good ways to fix such error?

Comment: This cannot work. It's impossible to compare protocols because basically any type can adopt the protocol. Imagine you have a type `Cat : Animal` and `Dog: Animal`. How you do compare the types?

Comment: An array of a protocol-type is _always_ a bad idea, whether its a generic protocol or not. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself If you really had to do this, you would need to use _type erasure_ (i.e. you'd need an equatable AnyAnimal type). Apple has a WWDC video about this: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/408/

Comment: I still don't get it. Before conforming to Equatable, I am allowed to have array of protocol. But, why once conforming to Equatable, I am prohibit from doing so? Why do you think array of protocol-type is a bad idea? I thought most main stream languages like Java, allow and welcome array of interface (protocol).

Comment: You are allowed to make an array of protocol but that doesn't make it a good idea.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng Java has its `isEqual()` designed differently. It's defined on `Object` (the language's universal supertype), and expects a parameter of type `Object`. I.e., any two objects of any type can be compared. It's up to the implementer of `isEqual()` to write something like `if (this.class != that.class) return false`. You can contrast this with C#'s `IEquatable<T>`, where `Equal(T? other)` requires the compared object to be a `T` (or `null`)...

Comment: You can see an example of that in `class Person : IEquatable<Person>` ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1.equals?view=net-6.0#system-iequatable-1-equals(-0))). The equals method ends up having the signature `bool Equals(Person? other)`, which is basically the same as the Self-requirement in Swift.Equatable. If you want generalized equality according to some custom notion (about Animals or whatever), you need to make your own business-logic-specific equality type, that *isn't* `Swift.Equatable`.

Comment: Our own Rob Napier made a great talk that covers exactly this, specifically about Equatable: https://youtu.be/_m6DxTEisR8?t=2538

Comment: @Alexander Thanks for the video. This is my life saver! - https://youtu.be/_m6DxTEisR8?t=2585

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Alexander and his pointed video resource - https://youtu.be/_m6DxTEisR8?t=2585

Here's is the good workaround, to overcome the current limitation of Swift's protocol.

```
protocol Animal {
    func isEqual(to: Animal) -> Bool
}

func isEqual(lhs: [Animal], rhs: [Animal]) -> Bool {
    let count0 = lhs.count
    let count1 = rhs.count
    
    if count0 != count1 {
        return false
    }
    
    for i in 0..<count0 {
        if !(lhs[i].isEqual(to: rhs[i])) {
            return false
        }
    }
    
    return true
}

// struct. By conforming Equatable, struct is getting an auto 
// implementation of "static func == (lhs: Dog, rhs: Dog) -> Bool"
struct Dog: Animal, Equatable {
    func isEqual(to other: Animal) -> Bool {
        guard let other = other as? Dog else { return false }
        return self == other
    }
}

// class
class Cat: Animal, Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: Cat, rhs: Cat) -> Bool {
        // TODO:
        return true
    }
    
    func isEqual(to other: Animal) -> Bool {
        guard let other = other as? Cat else { return false }
        return self == other
    }
}

var animals0 = [Animal]()
var animals1 = [Animal]()

// Instead of using
// if animals0 == animals1 {
// we will use the following function call

if isEqual(lhs: animals0, rhs: animals1) {
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This part of Swift can be a little confusing, and there are [plans to improve it](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0335-existential-any.md).

When you write something like  `a0: [Animal]`, you saying that your function takes an array argument, whose elements are protocol existentials (of the `Animal` protocol).

An existential `Animal` is an object that gives its user uniform access to all the requirements (properties, methods, subscripts, initializers, etc.) of the `Animal` protocol, regardless of the concrete type of the underlying conforming object (`Cat`, `Dog`, etc.).

In the new world post SE-0335, you code would have to be spelled like this:

```
func x(a0: [any Animal], a1: [any Animal]) -> Bool {
    return a0 == a1
}
```

The issue becomes more clear: there's no guarantee that `a0` and `a1` contain animals of the same type. It's now literally written in the code: they're arrays of *any* animal type. Each one can contain animals of any type, and there's no relationship between the types of the animals in `a0` vs in `a1`. This is an issue because `Equatable` is verify specific about its requirements: its `==` operator is only applicable to two objects of the same type.

To remedy this, you would need to make your function generic, to constrain `a0` and `a1` to contain objects of some particular type:

```
func x<A: Animal>(a0: [A], a1: [A]) -> Bool {
    return a0 == a1
}
```

Comment: you meant `a1: [A]`

Answer (score 0):

Protocol can't conform to Equatable. The reason is, that it requires Self. Self refers to the concrete(e.g. struct/class) type that conforms to the Equatable. If you want to be able to use protocol instead of concrete type for array, then you need to write compression function yourself:

```swift
protocol Animal {
    
    var name: String { get }
    
}

func compare(lhsAnimals: [Animal], rhsAnimals: [Animal]) -> Bool {
    guard lhsAnimals.count == rhsAnimals.count else { return false}
    for i in 0..<lhsAnimals.count {
        if lhsAnimals[i].name != rhsAnimals[i].name {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: That code doesn't compile

Comment: Sorry, I quickly wrote an answer without check, now corrected.

Comment: This is wrong you can definitely have an array of Animals. `let animals: [Animal] = [Dog(name: "Albert"), Dog(name: "Kiki"), Dog(name: "Caesar")]`

Comment: Ok, it seems that it is better to rewrite my answer.

Comment: This `for` loop could be simplified to just `zip(lhsAnimals, rhsAnimals).allSatisfy { $0 == $1 }`. It doesn't work though, because there's no guarantee the left and right sides of the equality are of equal types, which is a requirement for `==`.

Comment: @BulatYakupov your new edit doesn't compile

Comment: sorry, typo, fixed

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm a bit nervous, my second answer here, so there can be some mistakes :)

Comment: I will take more time to doublecheck everything next time :)